# Selecting from Manipulate for ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting

, Referring to yesterday's "Switching parameter lines on/off in a 3D parametric plot" ([Switching parameter lines on/off in a 3D parametric plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59351/switching-parameter-lines-on-off-in-a-3d-parametric-plot/59357#59357))

From reply by Bob Hanlon for example, can we pick up some option combinations resulting in two separate 3D plots  out of the  above full Manipulate set, approximately indicated as :

```
GrU= {uMesh True,uMesh=18, v Mesh False,Surface, Boxed -> False} and

GrV= {vMesh True, vMesh=10,u Mesh False,WireFrame, Boxed-> True}
```

and then combine them into a single plot by:

```
Show[GrU,GrV]
```

How  may it be done?

The motivation for this query is qualitatively the following.

If one cannot make a parametrization fully with 2 parameters u,v on a known surface which is undergoing a new parametric definition, sometimes one can start with a single parameter u on the surface while remaining on the surface and design/choose other new parameter v definition. The surface on which v is targeted, or going to be placed, can be a priori visualized while developing v.

For example the sphere can be parametrized *either* by a set of geodesics and parallel lines (latitudes,longitudes)*or* by two sets of great circle geodesics.

The above arose in finding a proper parametrization for Helmet Net. In the image there are Shown 2 sets of parallel circles, x-y, y-x are same but distance along arc of neighbor differential arcs is not same. It is not a *single* parametrization. Distances are more at 45 degree location. Attempt is to make all distances between nodes same in parametrization.It should be sure if all points in either set coincide.

[image: HelmetNet]

Comment: Wouldn't the single plot combination of those two be equivalent to just (uMesh=True, uMesh=18, vMesh=True, vMesh=10, Surface, Boxed=True)?

Comment: @BobHanlon I am trying to find out for Helmet Net example. If parametrization is available, it is ok as you suggested. In the image I attached, there is no developed parametrization known to me.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Change all Options of Plot Dynamically](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35444/change-all-options-of-plot-dynamically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional controls added to facilitate exploration:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]},
  {u, uMin, uMax},
  {v, vMin, vMax},
  Mesh -> {
    If[uMeshOn, uMesh, 0],
    If[vMeshOn, vMesh, 0]},
  Boxed -> boxed,
  Axes -> boxed,
  PlotStyle -> pltStyle,
  PlotRange ->
   {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-2.1, 2.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}],
 Row[{
   Control[{{uMin, 0, "u Min"},
     0, uMax - uDelta, uDelta,
     Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}],
   Spacer[5],
   Control[{{vMin, -Pi, "v Min"},
     -Pi, vMax - vDelta, vDelta,
     Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}]}],
 Row[{
   Control[{{uMax, 2 Pi, "u Max"},
     uMin + uDelta, 2 Pi, uDelta,
     Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}],
   Spacer[5],
   Control[{{vMax, Pi, "v Max"},
     vMin + vDelta, Pi, vDelta,
     Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}]}],
 Row[{
   Control[{{uMesh, 15, "u Mesh"}, 0, 36, 1,
     Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}],
   Spacer[5],
   Control[{{vMesh, 15, "v Mesh"}, 0, 36, 1,
     Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small}]}],
 Row[{
   Control[
    {{uMeshOn, True, "u Mesh"}, {True, False}}],
   Spacer[5],
   Control[
    {{vMeshOn, True, "v Mesh"}, {True, False}}],
   Spacer[5],
   Control[
    {{pltStyle, Automatic, "Plot Style"}, {Automatic -> "Surface", 
      FaceForm[] -> "Wire Frame"}}],
   Spacer[5],
   Control[{{boxed, True, "Boxed"}, {True, False}}],
   Spacer[5],
   Button[Style["Reset", Red, Bold],
    {uMin = 0, vMin = -Pi, uMax = 2 Pi, vMax = Pi,
     uMesh = 15, vMesh = 15, boxed = True,
     uMeshOn = True, vMeshOn = True,
     pltStyle = Automatic}]}],
 Initialization :> (uDelta = vDelta = Pi/12)]
```

[image]